# Windows Authentication not working on Chrome but works on Firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I have one application having windows authentication. I was working perfectly before but from last month it is not allowing to log in to any user for chrome browser. But it is working with firefox.
With unmasked url it works fine but unmasked url only works in intranet. Masked url is used in both intranet and extranet. The issue is only for masked url. We are using loadbalancing in for masked url. Not sure if that might be causinhg that issue in latest Crome.

Comment: Silly question: have you tried deleting cookies?

Comment: What do you it can not work on chrome? Chrome didn't pop up the login window? Try to use the newest edge. It uses the same kernel as chrome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.